# Add an image as frame of video using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

all day I'm trying through ffmpeg to add this frame to this video ..

```
    mpca86@mpca86-HPPro6300SFF:~/sklad/Stiahnuté$ ffmpeg -i 20190224_081118.mp4 -hide_banner
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '20190224_081118.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    ro.build.version.sdk: 28
    ro.build.version.release: 9
    creation_time   : 2019-02-24T07:11:42.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:17.81, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4564 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 896x1920, 4553 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 7:15, 27.29 fps, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-02-24T07:11:42.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
```

[image: Frame to video]

Is anyone willing to help me?

Comment: Another one similar case (but +video scaling) you can find here : https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/35541/add-video-in-front-of-image-background-using-ffmpeg

Answer (score 2):

Basic syntax is

`ffmpeg -i 20190224_081118.mp4 -framerate 30 -i frame.png -filter_complex "[0]pad=1920:1080:576:0[vid];[vid][1]overlay" -c:a copy -movflags +faststart out.mp4`

This pads the video to the size of the frame image, and then overlays the frame on top. You may need to adjust the horizontal placement of the video by adjusting the `x` value ib the pad filter, currently `576`.

Comment: Big THANKS!!! Finaly: https://youtu.be/xA797sSFcV0

Comment: Maybe you can say how to move video to front here? In case png has no transparent "center" region?